# Typescript: Class within Class

Tags: typescript

I have a class Moviecharacter which represents json data about movie characters aswell as an actor class which holds information about actors.
I want to add the Actor class into my Moviecharacter class without using duplicated attributes:

My versions for Actor and MovieCharacter are:

```
// actor class stores general information about an actor in a json file
export class Actor{
    name: string;
    id: number;
}

// duplicated attributes name and id:
export class MovieCharacter {
    name: string;
    id: number;
    character: string;
}
```

But i want something like this:

```
 // without duplicated Attributes:
export class MovieCharacter {
    Actor(); // not working
    character: string;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> // without duplicated Attributes:

Suspect you are looking for *inheritance*:

```
// actor class stores general information about an actor in a json file
export class Actor {
    name: string;
    id: number;
}

// Inherits name and id from Actor
export class MovieCharacter extends Actor {
    character: string;
}
```

## More

Some helpful docs : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/classes.html

Comment: great, inheritance was the thing i was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

You firstly need to specify the member as "name : type"

If you wanted to create a new instance of the class on construction you can do the following..

```
 class MovieCharacter {
    actor: Actor;

    constructor() {
        this.actor = new Actor();
    }
}
```